# Import error (E0337) while linking C++ and C++/CLI projects (.NET Core)

Tags: c++, .net, c++-cli, clr

I am currently trying to set up a .NET project. I have a existing back project in c++ that I want to display on a web interface. To do this I am trying to link my C++ to the .NET platforme via a *CLR Class Library .NET Core* (and ultimately link that to an *ASP.NET web interface* but that is the next step).

My problem comes when I try to import the original files to the C++/CLI project. When the file I try to import uses C++ vectors (`#include <vector>`) I get eight errors all containing `E0337 linkage specification is incompatible with previous "bsearch_s" (decalred at line 26)` in the file *corecrt_search.h* (being a windows 10 kit file). You can see full content of the errors on [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JhNE.png).

The other errors are respectively for functions qsort_s, bsearch, _lfind_s, _lfind, _lsearch_s, _lsearch and qsort at lines 35, 48, 64, 74, 83, 93 and 56.

No errors arise when I the imported file doesn't use vectors.

The file *corecrt_search.h* contains indeed two declaration of these functions each should be compiled in a different context. Here is a little extract of this file (hope this is enough).

```cpp
_CRT_BEGIN_C_HEADER

_Check_return_
_ACRTIMP void* __cdecl bsearch(...);


// Managed search routines
#if defined __cplusplus && defined _M_CEE
extern "C++"
{
    _Check_return_
    void* __clrcall bsearch(...);
}
#endif
```

I don't understand why compiling the CLI project creates a conflict...

Here is how I linked the two projects:

- I added the original project as a dependency to the CLR
- In Linker => Input => Delay loaded Dlls, I added original_project.dll (usefull to add the ASP.NET project afterwards I think)
- In C/C++ => General => Additional Include Directories, I added the path to the original project

I work on Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.4.2

*Does anyone knows how to prevent such an error to occur? Thanks a lot!*

Comment: Don't obfuscate the compile error please, the "XXX" and "XX" are very important.  And show a repro snippet.

Comment: I had the same issue. Its just the IntelliSense error. Seems to be a bug in IntelliSense. I changed the mode to Build Only and the error was gone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue. I was getting the same error when using

> vector and Mat(OpenCV)

Its just the IntelliSense error. Seems to be a bug in IntelliSense. 
I changed the mode to Build Only and the error was gone.

[image]