# "E225 __clrcall not allowed on function with ellipsis parameter" after upgrading a .sln file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to look at a code of a project from a few years ago (about 3 years from the files' dates) and when I opened the .sln file in Visual Studio 2019 I got the following message:

> PmcSimTester.sln: Visual Studio needs to make non-functional changes to this project in order to enable the project to open in released versions of Visual Studio newer than Visual Studio 2010 SP1 without impacting project behavior.

After hitting ok and trying to run the debugger, the file "corecrt_wconio.h" is opened in visual studio and I get 110+ errors of the same kind:

> E225 __clrcall not allowed on function with ellipsis parameter

Now, from my understanding it's an error related to incompatibility of an older project to newer environment. I couldn't find a solution to this problem.

Is there a way to make it work in VS19?

Answer (score 0):

Whether you have installed the Windows 10 SDK?
I suggest you could try to install the suitable windows 10 SDKs from the visual studio installer.

[image]

Comment: Yea they are all installed

Comment: @ArielElliassi Whether you have set the windows SDK in the property page.

Comment: I checked the project properties and under general the Windows SDK version is the latest (10.0.19041.0)

Comment: I think the problem might be linked to the use of "#include < iostream >", this "iostream" might refer to the file "corecrt_wconio.h" as an old way of doing things in C++. Is there a newer file to use instead of that "iostram"?

Comment: @ArielElliassi Try to check if the path you set in your project property->VC++ Directories is correct. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt`

Comment: It was in the "Include Directories" already, I tried adding it in a separate line but the errors still occur

Comment: Well, from this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59505952/import-error-e0337-while-linking-c-and-c-cli-projects-net-core changing to build only has solved the problem I guess, now I'm getting other error unrelated to this one