# E2255 _clrcall not allowed on function with ellipsis parameter

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am trying to upgrade project from visual studio 2010 to visual studio 2022.  I got 105 errors.
Most errors are: E2255 _clrcall not allowed on function with ellipsis parameter" and some of them are "'CHAR': redefinition; different basic types" on the line I defined :typedef int_fast8_t CHAR; "

I tried all the possible ways I found from this website. But it didn't work. Thank you so much for helping in advance!

Comment: _I got 105 errors._ Is that all? :) I'm refactoring, I started with over 4000!

Comment: Possible dup for your first issue (it's answered in the last comment): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68707118/e225-clrcall-not-allowed-on-function-with-ellipsis-parameter-after-upgrading

Comment: For your second issue, please post a representative code snippet.  My crystal ball is broken ATM.

Comment: thank you so much, Paul.  The E2255 errors happened on two files: corecrt_wstdio.h and stdio.h.

Comment: If it's happening on standard header file then the project has some `#define`s that are "messing up" the standard header files.  Look at the line(s) in question and search the project (both source/header files and project settings) for `#define`s that could alter things like the calling convention.

Comment: Note also that the WinAPI header files define `CHAR` see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/working-with-strings - this is probably conflicting with the project `typedef`

Answer (score 0):

Compared with VS2010, VS2022 has many changes. If your project can run normally in VS2010 and encounter many errors in 2022, the main reason may be that you have not installed the necessary environment. You could refer to my settings.

[image]

And then install the Windows SDK of the corresponding operating system.